# How to install ngSanitize?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use ngSanitize so that I can inject html content ( external) into my app. However I got stuck at the ngSanitize installation. If I add it into my app module it stops working . Should I download this from somewhere ? Angularjs docs don't say anything.

```
var crmApp = angular.module('crmApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'crmControllers',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngSanitize',
]);
```

Comment: After installing bower install angular-sanitize --save need to import ngsanitize in  angular.module('crmApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'crmControllers',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngSanitize',
]).???

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Install [bower](http://bower.io/). You want bower.

```
npm install -g bower
```

Go to your project root and install ngSanitize:

```
bower install angular-sanitize --save
```

`bower install` downloads the script for you. Include the JavaScript in your app:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Comment: hello ... the way you installed this ... was this for nodejs?? I mean if I am doing just good old fashioned html with javascript, this doesn't apply to me does it??

Comment: Bower is a package manager that is mostly used on the client side. That said, Bower falling out of favor a little bit. I would consider using NPM to manage dependencies. It'd be a good idea to understand what a package manger is even if you end up not using one right now.

Comment: well I have been playing with node, even bought a book 3 weeks ago (only read chapter 1 so far) ... but using it occurs WITHIN the node environment, whereas when I am building a good ole traditional site with traditional `<script src='some_file.js'>`, the whole bower (or npm) discussion is not relevant, right???? I understand that bower/npm are basically mechanisms to download code to my node world ... maybe I am still missing something ...

Comment: Package managers are relevant on the client side. Do some reading on package managers are used in a general sense. Keep going, I think it will click in time. Let's say someone else built `some_file.js`. Every time they release a new version do you want to have to visit the project's web site and download it and then update your project? I don't! Bower/NPM will do the boring stuff for you.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use CDN resources without download go to **https://code.angularjs.org/** and click on version you want .Will find all the various resources available there and then you can copy location straight into script tag:

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is discouraged to use in production environments. Read about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Answer (score 2):

install
`npm install --save angular-sanitize`

import in app module
`import ngSanitize from "angular-sanitize";`

add it to your module
`angular.module("app", [ngSanitize])`

use in component

```
controller: class appController {
  constructor($sanitize) {
    this.$sanitize = $sanitize;
    this.text = this.$sanitize('text to be sanitized');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to download and include it: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize