# Install ngsanitize for mobile angular ui.(angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jquery-mobile, mobile-angular-ui

I am using Mobile Angular Ui. I want to install ngsanitize. I have seen one link [How to install ngSanitize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986363/how-to-install-ngsanitize)

I have successfully installed

> npm install -g bower 
>   bower  install angular-sanitize --save

But when i putted in app.js then it is not works.

```
angular.module('Y', [
  'ngRoute',
  'mobile-angular-ui',
  'Y.controllers.Main',
   'ngSanitize'
])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:'home.html',  reloadOnSearch: null})
                .when('/cityPage', {templateUrl:'cityPage.html', reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/category-prduct', {templateUrl:'category-prduct.html',  reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/product-description', {templateUrl:'product-description.html',  reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/my-winni', {templateUrl:'my-winni.html',  reloadOnSearch: false})
                .when('/gift-box', {templateUrl:'gift-box.html',  reloadOnSearch: false});
});
```

I have import script in index.html.

```
> <script
> src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

But when i did changes in app.js, then it is not work.
I am using MOBILE ANGULAR UI frame work. I think its have differ approach. When i installed npm install -g bower and bower install angular-sanitize --save. Then one folder (angular-sanitize) created in bower components.But i import in app.js then my project is not run.