# HTML text not rendered in proper way from JSON in MOBILE ANGULAR UI

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, mobile-angular-ui

I am using MOBILE ANGULAR UI frame work. When i retrieved the Text(include tags) from JSON then text show with tags in .html file. I have seen one link but i did not get solution. This link is [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view).
I already install ngsanitize but when i include in app.js, then my project dont show anythink.

SCREEN SHOT:
[image]

App.js

```
angular.module('Y', [
  'ngRoute',
  'mobile-angular-ui',
  'Y.controllers.Main',
])
```

COTROLLER:

```
.controller('chooseProductDescription', function($scope, $http){
    $http({
        method:'get',
        url:'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgbdRjMVpe?indent=2',
        header:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    }).success(function(data,status,headers, config){   
        $scope.productDescription = data;   
        $scope.html = data;
        $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
    }).error(function(data, status,headers, config){

    })
})
```

ngsanitize is compulsory for the view of text? But i also tried ngsanitize, i have seen one more link that one is.[How to install ngSanitize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986363/how-to-install-ngsanitize)

i want to simple solution for the view of text.

HTML.

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in productDescription">
        {{cat.product.fullDescription}}
</div>
```

I read this link many time ([AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)) but i did not get solution till now. I am using mobile angular ui framework, may be its have different approach.

I want to show only text without tags in html page in MOBILE ANGULAR UI.
Please share your ideas.

Comment: I guess.. you are not including `ngSanitize` properly..

Comment: @Minato. When i include ngSanitize in app.js then my project is not work.

Comment: see this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1jDeAgE1c0GM249sUcF8?p=preview) for better understanding.. try including.. `angular-sanitize` after `angular` and before your `script`

Comment: Did you solve your problem..?

Comment: @Minato. No. I think i am using mobile angular ui, That one have different approach.. but i am not sure.

Comment: I don't think that'll be a problem

Comment: Can you explain me some think  more.

Comment: `{{cat.product.fullDescription}}` instead of this.. use `<span ng-bind-html="cat.product.fullDescription"></span>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103053/discussion-between-varun-sharma-and-minato).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess.. you are not including `ngSanitize` properly

see this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1jDeAgE1c0GM249sUcF8?p=preview) for better understanding.. try including.. `angular-sanitize` after `angular` and before your `script`

And in your **Markup**

instead of this `{{cat.product.fullDescription}}` use..

```
<span ng-bind-html="cat.product.fullDescription"></span>
```